# Libor reform: why SONIA stays, but EONIA is to be replaced by ESTER

Tags: libor

what is the reason that why SONIA stays, but EONIA is to be replaced by ESTER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both have been reformed, but the reformed version of SONIA retains its name, whereas the reformed EONIA is called €STR. EONIA has been kept alive to allow for 'smooth' transition to the new RFR (€STR), most likely because of the relatively large impact of the EONIA reform (circa 9 basis points compared to 1.5 basis points for SONIA). Please see further discussion in the comments below.

Comment: I believe (although don't take my word for it) the revised SONIA is significantly similar enough to the previous version that maintaining the same index was viable, whilst ESTER is more fundamentally different to EONIA

Comment: Potentially (1.5 basis points for SONIA vs 9 bp for EONIA), the SONIA reforms don't look trivial though: described here https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/markets/sonia-benchmark/administration-of-sonia#reform, and the impact on transactions is also substantial: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/markets/benchmarks/characteristics-of-sonia.pdf?la=en&hash=CD2ED351E94D9BB831250FBF97089108CA88052F

Comment: Helpful links.. So reformed SONIA has expanded the collection of data (albeit it is the same type of data - market broker transactions) and the impact at 1.4bps is actually quite small I would say. Whereas ESTER is a fundamentally new collection of data methodology (bank reported interbank lending to market broker transactions)

Comment: Tempted to say EONIA was relatively more flawed!

Comment: The choice of reformed Sonia by the UK makes moving to the new RFRs much easier than is the case in Europe and US.